# Hash function results on Reshift differs from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hash, amazon-redshift, md5, sha256

I have a table *hash_table* both in Microsoft SQL Server and AWS Redshift.

**Redshift**

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| phone | numeric(8,8) |
| name | string(2147483647) |

**SQL Server**

| Column Name | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| phone | numeric(8,0) |
| name | nvarchar(80) |

I want to extract a hash value from both tables so I can automate the value comparison. But even when I have the same values in both sides, the hash value from each field isn't the same.

I suppose it has sth to do with the data types but I haven't found anything regardig this matter on hash articles.

Am I doing sth wrong?

Here are the functions I've used and them results. At first I tryed with column name but, once the data type differs from each database, I decided using phone:

**Redshift**

`SELECT TOP (1)`

`len(TelephonyExtension) as PhoneLen,`

`TelephonyExtension as Phone,`

`MD5(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), phone)) as Hash`

`FROM hash_table`

Result:

| PhoneLen | Phone | Hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | cfcd208495d565ef62e7dff9f98764fa |

**SQL Server**

`SELECT TOP (1)`

`len(TelephonyExtension) as PhoneLen,`

`TelephonyExtension as Phone,`

`HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(nvarchar(30), phone)) as Hash`

`FROM hash_table`

| PhoneLen | Phone | Hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A46C3B54F2C9871CD91DAF7A932499X0 |

**I have also used sha2_256 instead of MD5 but the problem persists**

I expected the hash columns to have the same value in both systems for any type of column.

Answer (score 0):

Hash operates on strings. If the hash is different then the strings are likely different. Add      MD5(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), phone)) as Hash to you selects and post if there are differences.

I've done this a few times for clients and getting the strings to match exactly between two DBs can be tricky. Any extra spaces, non-printing chars, or puff of wind  can make this mismatch.

Comment: Yeh, quite tricky indeed. According to my last researches, hash uses the field`s binary data to create the hash code. Wich makes the match between DBs even trickier, once the data can be stored in different binary forms in order to enhance performance on each DB.

I`ve tried adding CONVERT(nvarchar(30), phone) to my SELECT but, as you can see in the description, the HASHBYTES() function returns sth different from the MD5 function.

The  solution we are currently working on is to generete those hashes via python by instanciating the datasets and converting it to strings.

Comment: Performing in python can work but as data size grows this can get very slow.  Exiting the full data from the database can be quite time consuming.  If it was me I'd want to know what type of data is causing mismatches and which data isn't.  Is it just non-ascii chars or everything?  Either endianness or character encodings could be the root and would suggest different work-arounds.  In some cases I've made my own hash processes that are simple, fast on even dog-slow DS, and give good data comparison coverage.